# New Google Photos API: 'isWriteable' not returned in album list

Tags: google-photos

Working with the recently-announced API (https://developers.google.com/photos/), I'm not seeing 'isWritable' in any album returned by the v1/albums endpoint, including albums created by my app.

I'm using the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary" scope, which both the documentation and the consent page indicate should allow uploads, so I'd expect isWritable=true for all the albums.

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I'm not able to upload media to any albums, even with the /auth/photoslibrary scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is partly a known issue. The `isWriteable` flag is not always returned when listing albums: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79497397

Also note that only albums that have been created by your application, given the correct scope has been granted, are writable (ie. the `isWriteable: true` property will be returned).

There is some more detail on the [Authentication and authorization scopes page](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authentication-authorization) in the developer documentation that explains the access that is available to applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The "known issue" you cite was created by me. The docs you cite were changed after I asked the question.  Sadly, the situation is just as unappealing as it was when I first reported these issues.